# Problems with JSTL forEach in JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf, foreach, jstl

Hi I got the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
>

<h:body>
 <c:forEach items="#{backingBean.personList}" var="person">
   <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" />
 </c:forEach>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This fails with:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus
```

I use jstl-impl-1.2.jar. Does anyone could help me on this one? Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about standard.jar?

Do you have both JARs in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: That was quick. I used the implementation 1.2 from https://jstl.dev.java.net/download.html which offers no standard.jar. I now tried the 1.1.2 jakarta version and it works. Thanks Marcel

Comment: If that did fix the problem, then it means that your web.xml was decared as servlet 2.4 or older instead of servlet 2.5 or newer. Try to declare the web.xml to max servlet version as supported by servletcontainer.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are missing a JSTL-api jar.

Classname search on [sonatype's nexus](https://repository.sonatype.org/) returned this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can [download it from this page](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) if you don't use maven.

You can also use [Findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/) to find [occurrences of the class](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html).

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves me right the JSTL core uses EL which has syntax like this `${}` rather than `#{}`.